# Notify the instance of the object when it is copied

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have a class with lazy initialization. For the sake of simplicity let's say that it is a database proxy. An object of the class can be in any of two states: `Ready` and `Initialized`. Initially, when you construct the object, you specify the database address, and the object becomes `Ready`, but doesn't connect to the DB yet. When you call any function which wants to access the DB the object performs the connection and changes its state to `Initialized`. I want the object to initialize when I do anything with it.

Including, I want to make this object copyable. However, I don't want to allow the uninitialized object to be copied: in this case two connections will be performed later. Instead I would like to notify the object when I'm trying to copy it so it can perform initialization, switch the state and only then copy to another object.

Here is a sample code with the behavior I'm trying to achieve.

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(Config conf) :
        initialized(false)
    {
        // process the config somehow
    }

    void tryInitialize() {
        if (!initialized) {
            // perform the connection
            initialized = true;
            connection = createConnection();
        }
    }

    void accessDatabase() {
        tryInitialize();
        // do something
    }

    Foo(const Foo& other) {
        other.tryInitialize(); // this is a problem because other is const
        initialized = true;
        connection = other.connection;
    }

private:
    bool initialized;
    DBConnection connection;
};
```

The problem still arises if I declare copy ctor as `Foo(Foo other)` because in this case the original object wouldn't be modified as well. Of course, this is achievable with move ctor, but I'd like to use copy ctor as well.

P.S. The real problem is not much about databases but complex enough to be explained here. So you can assume that no real world problems about databases matter here: connection attempts always succeed, having two instances of the same connection is OK, etc.

Comment: Why not `Foo(Foo& other)`?

Comment: Can you have a private `intialize()` function that forces the initialization if in the "Ready" state (no-op if already initialized). Then write a copy-constructor that calls `initialize()` before making a copy?

Comment: This situation might be a good argument for making the class members mutable, and `tryInitialize()` a `const` method.

Comment: P.S. You should also delete the assignment operator, or make it do something sensible.

Comment: It should be noted that lazy-initialised classes are a terrible pattern, and should be avoided at all cost. They effectively subvert the type safety by allowing un-initialised objects. Initialisation should happen in the constructor. If the object can’t be initialised yet, it shouldn’t exist in the type system. Unfortunately C++ itself also does this wrong by allowing the creation of unopened file streams.

Comment: @molbdnilo Because this kind of copy ctor doesn't allow temporaries on the rhs. I'm not sure if my question is still valid if rhs is a temporary, though.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I have several methods which are to be called with the uninitialized class (and modify the future connection somehow), so I can't do it in the ctor. This is a bad pattern, I agree.

Comment: @molbdnilo There might be a function which returned uninitialized connection. As soon as I assign it to the non-temporary value on the lhs, it becomes initialized and ready to use.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov In that case you shouldn’t modify the object itself but rather a builder object that, once ready, can be used to create your actual connection object.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Having the Builder would be the enterprise solution, you're right. I'm writing an ad-hoc library where the main aim is letting the end-user type as few code as possible; sometimes it is achieved at the expense of bad design. So this question is mostly a question of a trade-off.

Answer (score 3):

You can mark your private members as `mutable` and make you `tryInitialize()` method `const` (or you can write some other private initialize method with constness).

This solution is a bit dirty but anyway it solves your problem :)

Comment: mutable would not work for this, see example of mutable above.

Comment: @Nick Pavini, not, it works. The OP just need to modify members in `const` method (i.e. modify `initialized` and `connection` from `tryInitialize` method). Here is an [example](http://rextester.com/HFWN56613)

Comment: I stand corrected and have edited my post to support your position.

Answer (score 2):

If i'm understanding this correctly, you want a `copy` `constructor` that can modify the passed in `argument`. If this is true then what your are saying is correct, `foo( foo other )` would not work because that would only pass a `copy` of the `argument`, and `foo( const foo& other )` would not be modifiable in the `copy` `constructor`. The solution is simply `passing by reference`.

```
Foo(Foo& other) {
        initialized = true;
        other.tryInitialize(); // Now will be able to modify other
        connection = other.connection;
    }
```

Reference article below for `const` correctness of `copy` `constructors` below, and I quote,  " Pass by non-const reference ONLY if the function will modify the parameter and it is the intent to change the caller's copy of the data, otherwise pass by const reference."

> http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/

Reference article for `mutable` below, "mutable - applies to non-static class members of non-reference non-const type and specifies that the member does not affect the externally visible state of the class (as often used for mutexes, memo caches, lazy evaluation, and access instrumentation). mutable members of const classes are modifiable. (Note: the C++ language grammar treats mutable as a storage-class-specifier, but it does not affect storage class.)"

> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv

See example of using `mutable` from "Effective C++ Third Edition" by Scott Meyers, and apply for alternative solution to pass by reference.

```
class CTextBlock {
public:
    ...
    std::size_t length() const;
private:
    char *pText;

    mutable std::size_t textLength;
    mutable bool lengthIsValid;
};

std::size_t CTextBlock::length() const
{
    if(!lengthIsValid) {
        textLength = std::strlen(pText);
        lengthIsValid = true;
    }
    return textLength;
}
```

Comment: This is not a copy constructor.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes it is.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik This is my source, if you feel it is mistaken, would you please explain why?

Comment: Because the question is about a copy constructor. This is not a copy constructor.

Comment: @NickPavini Sam is right and you shouldn't beg for an upvote anyway. Are you here to help or for reputation mining?

Comment: @skypjack without prejudging if the answer is correct or helpful for OP I think `Foo(Foo& other)` is actually a copy constructor at least according to c++ standard [class.copy] point 2